# recursive solution not working as intended/ running into errors

Tags: c++, recursion, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow

I'm looking for some help on a problem that I vaguely inquired about before, which is solving 15-peg solitaire recursively.  I keep getting strange errors when I compile and run it, most of them say "stack overflow" or that I'm getting a seg fault.  This is what I have so far, where "board[15]" represents the 15 peg board, and "moves[36]" represents all of the possible moves that can be made.  The recursion is supposed to spot when there is only one peg left.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;                               

void solveGame(int a[15], int b[36][3], int c[15][4]);

void chooseMove (int a[15], int b[36][3], int openSpace, int c[15][4]);

int findEmpty (int a[15]);

int pegCount (int a[15]);

bool isPeg (int peg, int a[15]);

int usedVals[15] = {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};

int d = 0;

int index = 0;

int main ()
{
    int openSpace = 5;

    int board[15]= {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};

    board[openSpace] = 0;

    int alreadyMoved[15][4];                                                                                                        

    int moves[36][3] = {{0, 1, 3},
                        {0, 2, 5},
                        {1, 3, 6},
                        {1, 4, 8},
                        {2, 4, 7},
                        {2, 5, 9},
                        {3, 6, 10},
                        {3, 7, 12},
                        {3, 1, 0},
                        {3, 4, 5},
                        {4, 7, 11},
                        {4, 8, 13},
                        {5, 9, 14},
                        {5, 8, 12},
                        {5, 2, 0},
                        {5, 4, 3},
                        {6, 3, 1},
                        {6, 7, 8},
                        {7, 4, 2},
                        {7, 8, 9},
                        {8, 4, 1},
                        {8, 7, 6},
                        {9, 5, 2},
                        {9, 8, 7},
                        {10, 6, 3},
                        {10, 11, 12},
                        {11, 7, 4},
                        {11, 12, 13},
                        {12, 7, 3},
                        {12, 8, 5},
                        {12, 11, 10},
                        {12, 13, 14},
                        {13, 8, 4},
                        {13, 12, 11},
                        {14, 9, 5},
                        {14, 13, 12}};


    solveGame(board, moves, alreadyMoved);

    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        cout << alreadyMoved[i][0] << " " << alreadyMoved[i][1] << " " < <alreadyMoved[i][2] << endl;

    return 0;
}

// main recursive function
void solveGame (int a[15], int b[36][3], int c[15][4]
{
int empSpace;
int moveIndex;

    if (pegCount(a) < 2) {
        cout<<"game over"<<endl;
    } else {
        empSpace = findEmpty(a);
        chooseMove(a, b, empSpace, c);
        solveGame(a, b, c);
    }
}

// supposed to pick a move that is applicable to the board otherwise it find a new move
void chooseMove (int a[15], int b[36][3], int openSpace, int c[15][4])
{
int i = 0;

    while (1) {
        if (i < 36 && b[i][2] == openSpace && isPeg(b[i][0],a) && isPeg(b[i][1],a)) {
            a[b[i][0]] = 0;
            a[b[i][1]] = 0;
            a[b[i][2]] = 1;

            c[d][0] = b[i][0];
            c[d][1] = b[i][1];
            c[d][2] = b[i][2];
            c[d][3] = i;

            d++;

            index = 0;

            for (int v = 0; v < 15; v++)
                usedVals[v] = -1;

            break;
        } else if (i > 35) {
            a[b[c[d-1][3]][0]] = 1;
            a[b[c[d-1][3]][1]] = 1;
            a[b[c[d-1][3]][2]] = 0;

            c[d-1][0] = 0;
            c[d-1][1] = 0;
            c[d-1][2] = 0;
            c[d-1][3] = 0;

            usedVals[index] = openSpace;

            index++;

            int newOpen = findEmpty(a);

            chooseMove(a, b, newOpen, c);
        }

        i++;
    }
}

// counts the pegs on the board in order to cancel recursion
int pegCount (int a[15])
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        if (a[i] == 1)
            count++;
    return count;
}

// finds an empty space that hasn't already been found faulty 
int findEmpty (int a[15])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
            if(a[i] == 0 && i != usedVals[j] && usedVals[j] > -1)
                return i;
        }
    }
}


// tests if current index is a peg 
bool isPeg (int peg, int a[15])
{
    return a[peg] == 1;
}
```

Comment: Eek! Wall of code! Could you format the code please.

Comment: Have you tried running the program in a debugger? It will stop at the place of the error and you can check variables to see what might be wrong.

Comment: Please don't put that many empty lines everywhere it makes it hard to get a overview of your code. Furthermore fix your indention. Now for your problem: Did you try using a debugger? If you did, what did the stacktrace say, if not, why not?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, Yes I've tried that but it stops at places where I don't believe there could even be an error.  For example it stopped at "pegCount(int a[15])" a few times, but all that does is tally the pegs on a simple array, so I don't see where the problem could arrise..

Comment: Even when (if) the code is readable ... you haven't said what compiler warnings you get, and it's sensible to address that first. Then, if you get a segfault, do you get a core file? That would give you a stack trace. Then you'll have compiling code with a specific bug, and we might be able to help.

Comment: Right. Debug it. The recursion shouldn't go any deeper than the number of moves in a game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick glance shows a lot of potential problems, but I think it probably boils down to the way you are passing arrays.  Arrays are passed by reference and not by value, so the recursive function is working with a single copy of the array, which I don't think is what you want.  Therefore you are never finding the ending move, which will get you a stackoverflow from unlimited recursion.

Try allocating a new copy of the arrays at each level of recursion.  Some people will want you to use `new` or `malloc` for this, because they feel an introduction to C++ should be a trial by fire where you have to master memory management to do anything useful.  Instead, I would advise you not to use arrays at all; use a collection class that will work properly when passed by value (I think std::vector of POD will do this) and the collection class will create copies of your arrays the way your code seems to expect.

You may also be having a problem of doing a depth-first search in chooseMove, when you really want a breadth-first search.

Answer (score 0):

Stack overfow when using recursivity is pretty common. This is due to the fact that return values for function calls are stored into the stack, and the stack keeps filling as long as function does not return. If the recursivity goes too deep, you end up filling your whole stack and overflowing it, which also causes SEGV.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you get a stack overflow when your exit condition does not work, but here you are also passing your parameters by value, which might overflow your stack even in normal operation.

I suggest you pass your arrays by reference or better in a `std::vector`. An `std::vector` is a small object that holds the real data in a heap allocated space. You can even return those.

I also suggest that you start your program in a debugger, that is the simplest and most effective way to find out what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: passing naked arrays as parameters actually passes a pointer; little fear of SO there.